# Using (Squid) Caching Proxy with (HideMyAss) OpenVPN VPN

Tags: windows-7, proxy, openvpn, proxy-server

I've set up Squid proxy, and I confirmed it's working on my PC.
Note: To be able to use the Internet with better speed, I have to forward to another parent proxy (my university's proxy).

Now I'm using HideMyAss VPN (OpenVPN protocol), but without the squid, since I don't know how to configure them to work correctly.
Note: I'm using the university's proxy in HideMyAss VPN software so that I get good Internet connection, but if I use squid's proxy, it doesn't work.

So, how do I configure Squid to work with VPN?

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?